# MPMoviePlayerViewController won't play larger mp4 files

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch

What I have are 2 links to 2 versions of the same movie, one in lower definition the other in higher, both .mp4 format.

It plays the low-def just fine, but when I click the link for the HD version the movie player pops up like it should then dismisses itself back to the original view controller.  If I click it again, it works, but the first try usually fails.  Like something with threading is going on and succeeding or not.  From what I've read it's an issue with ARC but I can't seem to get it right.

I want to use the MPMoviePlayerViewController because I like how it by default acts as a modal popup.  I tried with a MPMoviePlayerController but you have to set the view then handle rotations it seems.

I'm not getting any crashes or any warnings in the log inside Xcode either.

Here's my code:

```
@interface VideoInfoViewController ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) MPMoviePlayerController *player;

@end

- (IBAction)playLowVideo:(id)sender {

    [self playVideoFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_video.video_url_low]];
}

- (IBAction)playHDVideo:(id)sender {

    [self playVideoFromURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_video.video_url_HD]];
}

- (void)playVideoFromURL:(NSURL *)url {

    MPMoviePlayerViewController *playerViewController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    _player = playerViewController.moviePlayer; 
    _player.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill;
    [_player prepareToPlay];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:playerViewController];
}
```

ETA:

found this tutorial: http://josebolanos.wordpress.com/2011/09/28/dismissing-mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-the-right-way/

```
- (void)playVideoFromURL:(NSURL *)url {

    MPMoviePlayerViewController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [self presentModalViewController:player animated:YES];
    [player.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
    [player.moviePlayer play];
}
```

still doesn't work.

Comment: thought I had a working solution, but it didn't work, updated code posted.

Comment: Does it work if you launch the app and choose the HD video first?

Comment: turns out on the service side that is supplying the HD videos they fail in a browser as well, so this is a problem with the host not the app.  But it would be nice to know a better way to handle when the ViewController dismisses.